# in SQL SELECT statement :conditionally removing comma operator from field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a select statement like

`SELECT 'Name' = customer_fname+ ', ' + customer_lname
                     FROM customers`

Its output is like:

```
peter, willson
jenny, Mark
```

Now, if customer_fname is null, then output will be:

```
, willson
    , Mark
```

If customer_lname is null then:

```
 peter, 
    jenny,
```

And if both customer_fname and customer_lname are null then only the comma will be displayed.

I want to remove the comma. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily I would suggest using the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) operator. However, as you need to check on both fields, the logic becomes a bit nasty. Therefore, I would suggest using a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN first_name IS NULL AND last_name IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN first_name IS NULL AND last_name IS NOT NULL THEN last_name
    WHEN first_name IS NOT NULL AND last_name IS NULL THEN first_name
    ELSE last_name + ', ' + first_name
END 
FROM customers
```

**EDIT** For dknaack - an ISNULL solution :)

```
SELECT ISNULL(last_name + ', ' + first_name, 
           ISNULL(last_name, 
               ISNULL(first_name, '')))
FROM Customers
```

Comment: @dknaack Please see edit for the ISNULL solution. It's not as readable as the SELECT so I would not recommend it, but it works...!

Answer (score 0):

You should use operator CASE and function ISNULL.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query: thanks

```
SELECT 'Name' =  
        (CASE WHEN customer_fname IS NULL OR customer_lname IS NULL THEN (customer_fname + ' ' + customer_lname )
            ELSE customer_fname+ ', ' + customer_lname END)
         FROM customers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case function in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 'Name' = customer_fname+ case when customer_fname is not null then ','  + customer_lname FROM customers
```

Answer (score 0):

careful with NULL values with [+] operator : 
unless you set the database parameter **CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL** to OFF,

NULL+'any non null string' returns NULL, not empty string

```
SELECT ISNULL(customer_fname,'')+ ISNULL(', '+ customer_lname,'') [Name]
FROM customers
```